# How change sphere size in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, size

I have a collision method with a sphere:

My code:

```
public class Colision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text points;
    int contador = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        //  GameObject halo = Instantiate(HaloPrefab) as GameObject;
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
        {
            //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
            //halo.transform.SetParent (transform, false);

            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            contador = contador + 1;
            points.text = "" + contador;
        }


        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube(Clone)")
        {
            //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            contador = contador + 1;
            points.text = "" + contador;
        }

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube1(Clone)")
        {
            //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            contador = contador + 1;
            points.text = "" + contador;
        }

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube2(Clone)")
        {
            //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            contador = contador + 1;
            points.text = "" + contador;
        }

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube3(Clone)")
        {
            //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            contador = contador + 1;
            points.text = "" + contador;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do when sphere collision with one block, the sphere becomes smaller?

Thanks for your time and help. Unity is more difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the size of an object as follows

Example :

```
//(this will make it 2x bigger)
col.transform.lossyScale *= 2;
```

or if you only want to modify a single axis

```
// This will make it 1 unity bigger in the X axis
col.transform.lossyScale += new Vector3(1,0,0);
```

naturally this works for any `transform` (which is present on all gameobjects)

Comment: Please speak English on Stackoverflow.